# Div2 inside another Div1. How to make these Div1 and Div2 to be appeared side by side

Tags: html, css

I have to create div2 inside div1. The problem here is I have to make those two div's side by side. I tried to apply float, margin-left but still I can't make it happen.

Code will be like

```
<div1> <form> <div2>here I have to write div2</div2></form><div1>
```

So, is there any chance that div1 and div2 appear side by side.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use absolute positioning.

Comment: Please post an image that shows how it should look

Answer (score 1):

I just made the left margin of div2 greater than the width of div1 and it worked for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
    #one{
     height: 100px;
     width:200px;
     border:1px solid black;
     background-color: blue;
     
       
    }
     #two{
     height: 100px;
     width:200px;
     border:1px solid black;
     margin-left:230px;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one"> 
<form>
<div id="two">
here I have to write div2
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

According to your question Here is your answer.

```css
div1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div2 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
   <div1>
 test
<form>
 <div2>here I have to write div2</div2>
 </form>
   <div1>
```